# How to SurfaceView multiple drawings on canvas with no drawing sync

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, surfaceview

I'm trying to do a simple app that changes the canvas background colour every 500ms, over the canvas I would like to create n circles that each vary their radius every x millisecond.

How can I do this if my sleep time in the "run()" method is dictated by the cavas colour change. Should I create a new thread for every circle and sync all of them?

Cleary I also need to take in consideration that the circles have to be drawn after the canvas background color change, since I would risk that the circles would not be visible due to background layer drawn obove the circles?

For this kind of job should I consider working with opengl?

This is my run():

```
public void run() {
            int i=0;
            Paint paint= new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);

            Log.d("ZR", "in running");
            while(running){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;
                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
                canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, 100, paint);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                Log.d("ZR", "in running: "+i +" count: "+j);
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `Thread.sleep()` would be to implement a timer to trigger your different drawing routines. Here is some pseudocode:

```
timeOfLastBackgroundChange = currentSystemTime()
timeOfLastCircleResize = currentSystemTime()
needsCanvasRedraw = false

while(running) {
    if (currentSystemTime() - timeOfLastBackgroundChange > 500) {
        changeBGColor()
        timeOfLastBackgroundChange = currentSystemTime()
        needsCanvasRedraw = true
    }

    if (currentSystemTime() - timeOfLastCircleResize > n) {
        resizeCircle()
        timeOfLastCircleResize = currentSystemTime();
        needsCanvasRedraw = true
    }

    if (needsCanvasRedraw) {
        drawUpdatedObjects()
        needsCanvasRedraw = false
    }
```

Basically, within your loop, you keep track of the last time you changed the background color and resized your circles. In every iteration of the loop, you check if enough time has elapsed to warrant another background change or circle resize. If it has, then you make the change and record the current time of the change so you can record the elapsed time for the next change. The `needsCanvasRedraw` flag lets you redraw only when something has changed rather than every loop iteration.